# How to control the display text in Antd Select Component

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Antd select component, Antd version 3.24.0. I need to control what is being displayed on the search box/ text field of the Select component based on user selection. I'm using select in multiple mode.

Expected:

1. When no options are selected, the placeholder attr kicks in and displays "Select options"
2. When all options in the list are selected, i want to display "All options selected". The users selections are visible in the dropdown popover when opened. That is all options would be checked, but instead of displaying as tags in the search box, will show this "All options selected" text.
3. In all other cases, i want to show the tags of options that were selected.

Actual:

1. When no options are selected, the placeholder attr kicks in and displays "Select options".
2. In all other cases like partial selections or complete list of options being selected, i see the options as tags being displayed in search box.

Attaching sandbox link for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-jones-dhpx3r?file=/index.js

I wrote a function renderValue, to calculate the display text. But this only seems to work when no options are selected, since im giving it in placeholder prop.

How do we achieve this?